# How to double integrate

Tags: integration

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwvwH.jpg)

The z axis is acceleration and the x and y axis is time. The painted area is $(1/2)at^2$, and I don't understand why the diagonal line is velocity instead of an area made by the acceleration axis and the time axis. Is there anything wrong with this graph? And how do you notate double integration to find the volume of this graph?

Answer (score 1):

Time is a single variable. You do *not* have two variables for time, as this would mean you can simultaneously be assigned two different points in time, which by our current physical laws, is impossible. Rather than double integration, you integrate twice in respect to the same variable. Given a constant acceleration $a$:
$$v = \int a\,dt = at$$
$$s = \int v \,dt = \int at \,dt = \frac{1}{2}at^2$$
Note that $s$ is postion, $v$ velocity, and $t$ is time.

**Edit:** If you are curious at all about double integration, I suggest looking at a multivariable calculus textbook. The general form of such equations is
$$\iint_V f(x,y) \,dy\,dx = C$$
where you integrate with bounds in respect to one variable, then in respect to the other in order to return a volume.

Comment: I would also recommend https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus